# Search bar with magnifying glass inside using CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, svg, search

I am trying to code a search bar with a magnifying glass icon inside the bar and no search button. I have found an example resource that I am basing my code after: [Search Icon Inside Input](https://nikitahl.com/search-icon-inside-input).

I am having difficulty getting the magnifying glass icon to even appear. Also, there is the issue of the search bar itself not being vertically aligned within my primary-nav container.

I am using the URL encoder for SVG tool at [URL Encoder for SVG Tool](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) and the font awesome icon with the background tag:

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
```

Here is a snippet of my style.css:

```
/* || PRIMARY MENU || */

.primary-nav {
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: darkgray;
    display: inline;
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    z-index: 3;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.search-container {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
}

form .no-submit {
    width: 180px;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid currentColor;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 0;
}

input .nosubmit {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 9px 4px 9px 4px;
    background-image: transparent url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 512 512'%3E%3C!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.0.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. --%3E%3Cpath d='M500.3 443.7l-119.7-119.7c27.22-40.41 40.65-90.9 33.46-144.7C401.8 87.79 326.8 13.32 235.2 1.723C99.01-15.51-15.51 99.01 1.724 235.2c11.6 91.64 86.08 166.7 177.6 178.9c53.8 7.189 104.3-6.236 144.7-33.46l119.7 119.7c15.62 15.62 40.95 15.62 56.57 0C515.9 484.7 515.9 459.3 500.3 443.7zM79.1 208c0-70.58 57.42-128 128-128s128 57.42 128 128c0 70.58-57.42 128-128 128S79.1 278.6 79.1 208z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") no-repeat 13px center;
    background-position: 10px center;
}

input[type="search"] {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: inherit;
}

input[type="search"]::placeholder {
    color: white;
}

input[type="search"]:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #3f69a8;
    border-color: #3f69a8;
    outline: none;
}
```

As well as my navigation.php view:

```
 <div class="search-container">
        <form class="no-submit">
            <input class="no-submit" type="search" placeholder="Search..." method="GET">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML doesn't appear to include the `<i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></I>` anywhere.  Can you put these separate bits of code together so we can see what you're actually doing?

Comment: From what I understand, you can't put the icon tag into the search input. You have to use the SVG version of the icon. So, I didn't use the ```<i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></I>``` in the code but used the URL Encoder Tool.

Comment: ``` input .no-submit { background-image: transparent url("data:image/svg+xml, ``` is where the SVG comes into play.

Comment: Most importantly you put your whole SVG into `url()`. You should only put a link to the SVG file. Also, there are too many issues with your CSS. Like wrong selectors `.nosubmit` should be `.no-submit`, `input .no-submit` means you want `.no-submit` inside of `input` and not `input` with `.no-submit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of issues in your code so let's go through them one by one.

**1. Wrong selector**

`input .nosubmit` isn't pointing at anything. Your class is named `.no-submit` and if you want to select `input` with the specific class you have to write it like this `input.no-sumbit`. Your selector is looking for `.no-submit` in `input` element.

**2. Wrong usage of `background`**

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) is a great example of how to use `background` in CSS. I haven't found usage of `background` where you write all parameters in a single property, as you did (I am not saying it doesn't work) so I decapsulated it into more properties. And when you want to add an image in `url()` better way is to insert the path to the image and not inside of the SVG file. For example, I choose a random magnifying glass icon and imported it like so:

```css
 background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Magnifying_glass_icon.svg") ;
```

You can also import your local file it doesn't have to be online. Just change the URL for relative or absolute path to the SVG.

**3. Using `background` when you need only `background-color`**

It may not matter most of the time but in your code having `background: transparent` removes your background images so you need to use `background-color: transparent`.

I believe there are more mistakes in your code but these are the worst one and your code will not work with them.

Here is working code snippet:

```css
/* || PRIMARY MENU || */

.primary-nav {
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: darkgray;
  display: inline;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  z-index: 3;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.search-container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
}

form .no-submit {
  width: 180px;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 0;
}

input.no-submit {
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 9px 4px 9px 4px;
  /* You can use your image but having cleaner code is better, so I suggest saving the file and just linking it*/
  /*background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 512 512'%3E%3C!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.0.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. --%3E%3Cpath d='M500.3 443.7l-119.7-119.7c27.22-40.41 40.65-90.9 33.46-144.7C401.8 87.79 326.8 13.32 235.2 1.723C99.01-15.51-15.51 99.01 1.724 235.2c11.6 91.64 86.08 166.7 177.6 178.9c53.8 7.189 104.3-6.236 144.7-33.46l119.7 119.7c15.62 15.62 40.95 15.62 56.57 0C515.9 484.7 515.9 459.3 500.3 443.7zM79.1 208c0-70.58 57.42-128 128-128s128 57.42 128 128c0 70.58-57.42 128-128 128S79.1 278.6 79.1 208z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") ;*/
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Magnifying_glass_icon.svg");
  background-size: 13px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 10px center;
}

input[type="search"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 8px 7px 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: inherit;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

input[type="search"]::placeholder {
  color: white;
}

input[type="search"]:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #3f69a8;
  border-color: #3f69a8;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container">
  <form class="no-submit">
    <input class="no-submit" type="search" placeholder="Search..." method="GET">
  </form>
</div>
```

Also, I have added padding so the text isn't over your magnifying glass.

Answer (score 4):

For putting the magnifying glass icon in the input, we use a Unicode character in the placeholder.

```
<input type="search" name="s" value="" style="width: 100%; margin: 0;" placeholder="&#128270;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Magnifier icon is present in google icons. Try this code:

```html
<head>
   <style>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
   <style>
</head>
<body>
   <i class="material-icons">search</i>
</body>
```